# In Geany, how can I scroll past the end of a file?

Tags: geany

When I'm editing a text file, I like to be able to scroll to a point where the last line of the file (or edit buffer) is somewhere in the middle of the screen (i.e., not at the bottom line of the window). 
When I use an editor that doesn't support this, I tend to insert a ton of blank lines at the end, which I think might be a bad habit ;D. 
Many text editors / IDEs seem to support this, but I haven't found a similar option in Geany yet. Is there an option for that?

In case it is not clear what I mean:

[image: atom-no-scroll-past-end]

This is the regular behaviour in most text editors. In Atom, you can change the setting "Scroll Past End" and then you can do this:

[image: atom-scroll-past-end]

This is (and has always been) supported in `vi`
when you scroll with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>,
or go to a line near the end and type <kbd>z</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

[image: "vi" window with the last line of the edit buffer near the top of the window]

Now I can have the last line of the file
at or near the top of the editor window. 
I'd like to do the same thing in Geany; how can I do it?

Comment: The images helped to explain your question, but I found the words (“scroll past the last line of a text file”) confusing.   Apparently this is standard terminology in Atom, but I’ve never used Atom.   I rewrote some of your text and added another illustration; you are, of course, free to change them back.

Comment: I found this note on https://www.geany.org/Support/PluginWishlist - "Make vertical scrolling stop at end of file; don't scroll past the end (or make it an option) - GUI pref added in Geany 0.15". This indicates that scrolling past the end of the file was already possible at some point, but I can't seem to find this GUI pref...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it: Under Edit -> Preferences -> Editor -> Display, there is the option "Stop Scrolling at last line". It is enabled by default and you'll have to untick the checkbox to allow scrolling past the last line.

[image: Stop scrolling at last line]